# Laravel Request has array but iteration error "Trying to get property 'product' of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, request

When I used

```
return $request->all();
```

network preview tab

```
  0 => array:10 [
    "id" => 1
    "user_id" => 1
    "product_id" => 1
    "brand_id" => 1
    "quantity" => 2
    "total" => "90000"
    "created_at" => "2021-05-21T07:48:34.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-05-21T07:48:34.000000Z"
    "product" => array:10 [
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "S1 Pro"
      "category_id" => 1
      "sub_category_id" => 1
      "brand_id" => 1
      "buy_price" => "40000.00"
      "sell_price" => "45000.00"
      "description" => "this is a new phone"
      "created_at" => "2021-05-20T06:02:28.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2021-05-20T06:02:28.000000Z"
    ]
    "brand" => array:4 [
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Vevo"
      "created_at" => "2021-05-20T05:48:01.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2021-05-20T05:48:01.000000Z"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:10 [
    "id" => 2
    "user_id" => 1
    "product_id" => 2
    "brand_id" => 2
    "quantity" => 1
    "total" => "195000"
    "created_at" => "2021-05-21T08:49:47.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-05-21T08:49:47.000000Z"
    "product" => array:10 [
      "id" => 2
      "name" => "Note 20 ultra"
      "category_id" => 1
      "sub_category_id" => 2
      "brand_id" => 2
      "buy_price" => "180000.00"
      "sell_price" => "195000.00"
      "description" => "A new phone a new Era"
      "created_at" => "2021-05-21T06:39:43.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2021-05-21T06:39:43.000000Z"
    ]
    "brand" => array:4 [
      "id" => 2
      "name" => "Samsung"
      "created_at" => "2021-05-21T06:37:54.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2021-05-21T06:37:54.000000Z"
    ]
  ]
]
```

But when Im using foreach loop to access every item it give error of "Trying to get property 'product' of non-object"

method I'm using

```
    public function sellProduct(Request $request){
        // dd($request->all());
            $cardData = $request->all();
            foreach ($cardData as $value) {
                return $value->product;
            }
    }
```

please help to resolve this issue, basically I'm creating a cart app through request I'm getting all the details and product

Comment: If `$value` is an array, then you need to use Array access, `$value['product']`. Object access (`->product`) is only for objects, like `stdClass`, or Model instances, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the product like `$value['product']` since it's an array and not an object.